# How to Update node.js from 0.10.xx to 4.6?

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5

I've install node in my Laravel project using `yum --enablerepo=epel install nodejs npm`.

`node -v` tells me i'm at version `v0.10.36`

Now I wanted version 4.6, but not sure how to get it installed.

Then I found these instructions, tried them:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
```

and got:

```
 install : node-v6.6.0
 mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/6.6.0
 fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.6.0/node-v6.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
 ######################################################################## 100.0%
 installed : v6.6.0
```

When I do `node -v`, I still get `v0.10.36`

Should I uninstall node with yum and try something else?

Will uninstalling break something in my Laravel project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing node first, then do a clean install.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that. Will `yum uninstall node` delete the `node_modules` folder in my Laravel project?

Answer (score 0):

Use `nvm` https://github.com/creationix/nvm which is the Node Version Manager.  It makes it much easier to switch versions.  Then you will need to test your code again to see if there are any breaking compatibility issues and review the newer version of the docs.

BTW as of writing, Node v7 is in beta and brings some significant optimizations over the version you are currently upgrading too.

Comment: Thanks, will give `nvm` a try